# How to convert NumPy arrays obtained from cv2.findContours to Shapely polygons?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, shapely

I am using CV2 to find contours from an image and then converting them into polygons using Shapely. I am currently stuck because when I try putting one of the contour arrays into `Polygon()` from Shapely it throws an unspecified error.

I have double-checked that I imported everything I needed, and that creating a Shapely polygon works when I manually enter the array coordinate points.

Here is the problematic section of the code:

```
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
testcontour = contours[1]

ply = Polygon(testcontour)
```

Where the list of contours looks like this:

```
contours = [np.array([[[700, 700]],
                      [[700, 899]],
                      [[899, 899]],
                      [[899, 700]]]), 
            np.array([[[774, 775]], 
                      [[775, 774]],
                      [[824, 774]],
                      [[825, 775]],
                      [[825, 824]],
                      [[824, 825]],
                      [[775, 825]],
                      [[774, 824]]]), 
            np.array([[[200, 200]],
                      [[200, 399]],
                      [[399, 399]],
                      [[399, 200]]]), 
            np.array([[[274, 275]],
                      [[275, 274]],
                      [[324, 274]],
                      [[325, 275]],
                      [[325, 324]],
                      [[324, 325]],
                      [[275, 325]],
                      [[274, 324]]])]
```

The error I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-4124f49b42e1> in <module>
----> 1 ply = Polygon(testcontour)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geocomp\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py in __init__(self, shell, holes)
    238 
    239         if shell is not None:
--> 240             ret = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
    241             if ret is not None:
    242                 self._geom, self._ndim = ret

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geocomp\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py in geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)
    492 
    493     if shell is not None:
--> 494         ret = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)
    495         if ret is None:
    496             return None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\geocomp\lib\site-packages\shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py()

AssertionError:
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason `cv2.findContours` returns each contour as a 3D NumPy array with one redundant dimension:

```
>>> contours[1]
array([[[774, 775]],
       [[775, 774]],
       [[824, 774]],
       [[825, 775]],
       [[825, 824]],
       [[824, 825]],
       [[775, 825]],
       [[774, 824]]])
```

but Shapely expects a 2D array in this form ([see the docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#numpy-and-python-arrays)):

```
array([[774, 775],
       [775, 774],
       [824, 774],
       [825, 775],
       [825, 824],
       [824, 825],
       [775, 825],
       [774, 824]])
```

So, what we can do is to use [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) to remove that redundant dimension, and use the result to obtain our polygon:

```
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

contour = np.squeeze(contours[1])
polygon = Polygon(contour)
print(polygon.wkt)
# POLYGON ((774 775, 775 774, 824 774, 825 775, 825 824, 824 825, 775 825, 774 824, 774 775))
```

---

In case if you want to convert all of the contours at once, I would do it like this:

```
contours = map(np.squeeze, contours)  # removing redundant dimensions
polygons = map(Polygon, contours)  # converting to Polygons
multipolygon = MultiPolygon(polygons)  # putting it all together in a MultiPolygon
```

The resulting `multipolygon` will look like this:

[image]

And to get the second polygon from here you would just write:

```
my_polygon = multipolygon[1]
print(my_polygon.wkt)
# POLYGON ((774 775, 775 774, 824 774, 825 775, 825 824, 824 825, 775 825, 774 824, 774 775))
```

Answer (score 4):

Below is code which takes into account also hierarchy of contours. It recursively walks through the hierarchy structure and adds/subtracts child contours in alternating manner.

The code also handles special cases when OpenCV returns trivial contours (single point) or polygons which are not shapely-valid.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read and threshold image
img = cv2.imread('/path/to/image')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,img_th = cv2.threshold(gray,185,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours and hierarchy
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img_th, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hierarchy = np.squeeze(hierarchy)
print("Number of contours found = " + str(len(contours)))

# Plot image with contours
cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (255, 0, 0), 3)
plt.imshow(img,origin='lower')
plt.show()

# Define function to merge individual contours into one MultiPolygon
def merge_polygons(polygon:MultiPolygon,idx:int,add:bool) -> MultiPolygon:
    """
    polygon: Main polygon to which a new polygon is added
    idx: Index of contour
    add: If this contour should be added (True) or subtracted (False)
    """

    # Get contour from global list of contours
    contour = np.squeeze(contours[idx])

    # cv2.findContours() sometimes returns a single point -> skip this case
    if len(contour) > 2:
        # Convert contour to shapely polygon
        new_poly = Polygon(contour)

        # Not all polygons are shapely-valid (self intersection, etc.)
        if not new_poly.is_valid:
            # Convert invalid polygon to valid
            new_poly = new_poly.buffer(0)

        # Merge new polygon with the main one
        if add: polygon = polygon.union(new_poly)
        else:   polygon = polygon.difference(new_poly)

    # Check if current polygon has a child
    child_idx = hierarchy[idx][2]
    if child_idx >= 0:
        # Call this function recursively, negate `add` parameter
        polygon = merge_polygons(polygon,child_idx,not add)

    # Check if there is some next polygon at the same hierarchy level
    next_idx = hierarchy[idx][0]
    if next_idx >= 0:
        # Call this function recursively
        polygon = merge_polygons(polygon,next_idx,add)

    return polygon

# Call the function with an initial empty polygon and start from contour 0
polygon = merge_polygons(MultiPolygon(),0,True)
```

Results: [Sample image with contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Pym.png) and [final shapely multipolygon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czFcL.png).