# How to transform contours obtained from OpenCV to SHP file polygons?

Tags: python, opencv, polygon, shapely

I have successfully extracted contours from a mask image, using OpenCV:

```
image = cv2.imread(file)

lower = np.array([240, 240, 240])
upper = np.array([255, 255, 255])
shape_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(shape_mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_CCOMP,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Now how do I go on to map this contours into a list of polygons (with holes) with shapely to export them as a SHP file?

Partial answer is given here:
[How to convert NumPy arrays obtained from cv2.findContours to Shapely polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965493/how-to-convert-numpy-arrays-obtained-from-cv2-findcontours-to-shapely-polygons)

However, this ignores the case of having holes inside the polygons. How would I go on to get all polygons?

Comment: What should happen with multiple nested contours? We can't, for example, represent three nested contours as a Shapely Polygon with a hole.

Comment: I thought about this also. The solution I found on GitHub (see below) deals with this by creating a MultiPolygon which contains 1st contour as a Polygon with hole (2nd contour), 3rd contour also as a Polygon with hole, etc. I tested it and it works quite well (opens nicely in QGis). The key for this is the "cv2.RETR_CCOMP" flag in the function cv2.findContours.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:
https://michhar.github.io/masks_to_polygons_and_back/

Helper to create MultiPolygons from a masked image as numpy array:

```
def mask_to_polygons(mask, epsilon=10., min_area=10.):
    """Convert a mask ndarray (binarized image) to Multipolygons"""
    # first, find contours with cv2: it's much faster than shapely
    image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(mask,
                                  cv2.RETR_CCOMP,
                                  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    if not contours:
        return MultiPolygon()
    # now messy stuff to associate parent and child contours
    cnt_children = defaultdict(list)
    child_contours = set()
    assert hierarchy.shape[0] == 1
    # http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html
    for idx, (_, _, _, parent_idx) in enumerate(hierarchy[0]):
        if parent_idx != -1:
            child_contours.add(idx)
            cnt_children[parent_idx].append(contours[idx])
    # create actual polygons filtering by area (removes artifacts)
    all_polygons = []
    for idx, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        if idx not in child_contours and cv2.contourArea(cnt) >= min_area:
            assert cnt.shape[1] == 1
            poly = Polygon(
                shell=cnt[:, 0, :],
                holes=[c[:, 0, :] for c in cnt_children.get(idx, [])
                       if cv2.contourArea(c) >= min_area])
            all_polygons.append(poly)
    all_polygons = MultiPolygon(all_polygons)

    return all_polygons
```

Credit for creating these helper functions:

> the original source of these helpers was a Kaggle post by Konstantin
>   Lopuhin [here](https://www.kaggle.com/lopuhin/full-pipeline-demo-poly-pixels-ml-poly) - you'll need to be logged into Kaggle to see it

Comment: This works great to create shapes that are usable with some things, however, the MultiPolygon is always shapely / GEOS "invalid" for the contours I pass and so this breaks most tools. I've been fiddling with this code to ensure valid polygons are created from the contours but I'm not having much luck.. any ideas?