# Intersection area between a numpy array and a shapely polygon

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, shapely

I would like to calculate an area of the intersection of a shapely polygon, and a mask (numpy.array):

```
plt.plot(*building.exterior.xy, color='brown', linewidth=4)
plt.plot(*parcelle.exterior.xy, color='orange', linewidth=4)
plt.imshow(thr, origin='upper', extent=[x_left, x_right, y_bottom, y_top], cmap='Greys')
```

[image]

I would like to be able to calculate the green area below :

[image]

For this, I tried using the method described here : [How to transform contours obtained from OpenCV to SHP file polygons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971260/how-to-transform-contours-obtained-from-opencv-to-shp-file-polygons)

```
mask_to_polygons(np.flip(thr, 0))
```

[image]

```
plt.plot(*parcelle.exterior.xy)
plt.plot(*building.exterior.xy)

mask_pol = translate(mask_to_polygons(np.flip(thr, 0)), x_left, y_bottom)
for geo in mask_pol:
    plt.plot(*geo.exterior.xy, color = 'green')
```

However, the result is not satisfactory :
[image]

Indeed, the bounds of the MultiPolygon mask_pol are not the dimensions of the thr array :

```
> mask_pol.bounds
(0.0, 0.0, 511.0, 511.0)
> thr.shape
(256, 256)
```

So, I'm wondering if the option to switch from mask to multipolynom shapely is the right one. I could also try to switch from shapely polynomials to masks. Are there better methods to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several tries, I came to the conclusion that the easiest way is to create a mask from the shapely polygon, this using [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It is then necessary to carry out meter - pixel conversions to obtain the total area.